# Added Colums in table of SQL not showing in Access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I am working on SQL Server Management Studio 2012 where my database is situated, but my operating system runs on Access itself which is linked to SQL server. I have inserted some columns into a table on SQL, but when I want to add these fields into my existing Access report, these new columns does not show on the available fields to insert, although they do on SQL. What am I doing wrong or not doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you miss is to relink the table in Access.

This will update the Fields collection.

Comment: I have done this already, linking the tables again in ms-access, but still not showing

Comment: I Managed to trace the columns I have added, now Access does not allow me to add any records?

Comment: Then you miss either a timestamp field in the SQL Server table or to tell, when linking, which field is the primary key.